# Here is my database: Is there any way to extract a list of the amount of times the same book has been borrowed alongside the title_name?

Tags: sql, mysql

[image: image of database]

I have attempted to use inner joins but not sure which would connect where? Do I need to add another FK somewhere?

```
SELECT user_name, fkbook_id
FROM users
INNER JOIN loans        
ON
user_id = fkuser_id
ORDER BY fkbook_id;
```

i've managed to extract the list of all the book_id's borrowed including any duplicate copies, but not sure how to get the title_name or if this is even possible? Any help/guidance is appreciated

Comment: Can you build a DB Fiddle to reproduce the database table structure and some sample data?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include (as formatted **text**) a relevant sample data and the desired output.

Comment: Aside: is the relationship between `title` and `book` 1:many? I'm a bit confused as to why `title` isn't an attribute of `books` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Follow your diagram - you'll need to `JOIN` through from `loans` -> `books` -> `title`:

```
SELECT users.user_name, loans.fkbook_id, title.title_name
FROM users
INNER JOIN loans ON users.user_id = loans.fkuser_id
INNER JOIN books ON loans.fkbook_id = books.book_id
INNER JOIN title ON books.fktitle_id = title.title_id
ORDER BY fkbook_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.book_id, t.title_name, COUNT(l.loan_id) As TimesBorrowed
FROM loans l
INNER JOIN books b ON b.book_id = l.fkbook_id
INNER JOIN title t on t.title_id = b.fktitle_id
GROUP BY b.book_id, t.title_name
```

Odd to use varchar fields for the IDs. You'd typically want those to be numeric incrementing values, and if you're concerned the database might actually get big enough to overflow a multi-billion item integer you use a guid or larger int type. But NOT varchar.

Also odd to use int values for the dates, though MySQL has history here around unix timestamps.